# From the third week ( when does it actually begin)

Tags: meaning

This describes a certain natural process that takes 15 weeks

It describes what a certain component looks like at some point in time during a naturallly occurring process

What I don't get is if it means it appears this way starting in the third week or after ?

Here's the full sentence

"The malleus first appears as a cartilage model from the third week"

Thanks again for you support guys

Answer (score 1):

If you have an appointment the third Monday of the month -- then you count Mondays. If you have an appointment the third week of the month and the month started early in the week, then you count as if the month started on Sunday. If the week started late in a week -- ask.

English is confusing when it comes to time and dating. Different countries and regions handle it differently.To me this Monday is Feb 27th and next is March 6th. To my husband, next Monday is Feb 27th.

The most simple fix is to be specific. I will see you on the 14th of March.

On edit: If you were running a scientific experiment or a report and the time frame was three weeks, count 21 days from the time you started. If it isn't specific, still count 21 days and check to see if things are coming to fruition.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: @Obad So did my answer cover it or are you still confused?

Comment: I'm really sorry , but i tried and i still don't understand your explanation. For the above sentence , and in the described context. Does this mean it appeared sometime during the third week ? Or after ?

Comment: I assume that it takes three weeks 'approximately' for "the malleus **to** first appear(s) as a cartilage model ". To me, and I again assume this is science/medicine (about which I know little or nothing) -- that in about or around/in approximately 21 days the malleus starts to form or appear.  So that time frame is when you start to check for it or to know that it is beginning to appear. At approximately 6 weeks into a pregnancy,  a baby's  nose, mouth, and ears are beginning to take shape. This doesn't mean **exactly** 42 days. It means around this time.  Did this help?

Comment: It differs from case to case. That's why i didn't mention it at first. I wanted to know what would the genral expression imply. Like if i say "exams start from the third week of the semester" would that mean the the first exam is in the third week ? Or after ? Or does it differ according to the user of the sentence. You get my point ? Sorry again

Comment: The semester starts on week one, right? Week two, no exams. Week three, starting the Monday approximately 21 days after the start of the semester, the exams begin. I say approximately because often a semester starts after a holiday and so might begin on a Tuesday or Wednesday. That would still be week one, in my opinion, even if the week was shortened. This only applies to this sort of example. Is this not the same where you are from?

Comment: I still don't get it . You are saying for the latest example that exams start after 21 days. This means after the third week is finished. Which is contradicting with the ansewr that was given on my other question that was marked as a duplicate. The answer said that normally it means from the beginning of the third as "from" indicates a starting point.i.e same as "starting from" , but you say that it means after the third week.

Comment: Or do you mean that the third week starts after 21 days to some ?

Comment: I think now I am confused. I should know better than to try answering these questions! :wink:  Nope, I was wrong. The third week would start  after 14-15 days.

Comment: So then , its correct to apply what you said after 14 days and not the 21 , right ?

Comment: yes, that's correct -- imo.